# Will the members of a union member call their own destructors in this scenario?

Tags: c++, destructor, unions

Will a class with an empty dtor, call it's member's dtors when it's own is explicitly called from within a union?

This is kind of tough to word, hopefully the psuedo-code is more straight-forward.  In this example, would `Texture::~Texture()` call `source.bitmap.pixels.~vector()` implicitly?

```
struct Bitmap{
    ~Bitmap(){} // empty dtor

    // members
    std::vector<uint8> pixels;  // <-- will this dealloc when ~Bitmap() is called manually?
};

struct Texture{
    ~Texture(){
        // assume sourceType is 1
        switch(sourceType){ 
        case 1:
            source.bitmap.~Bitmap();
            break;
        }
    }

    // members
    uint sourceType;
    union Source{
        Source(){}
        ~Source(){}

        // members
        Bitmap bitmap;
    }source;
};
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly I think you are asking : _"How does a class that contains a member union know how to destroy the active member of that union?"_

Comment: Notice that you have `std::variant` instead of manual `union`.

Comment: Writing it out and looking at it on SO, I think my real question may just be 'does `Bitmap::~Bitmap()` know to destroy `Bitmap::pixels`, even if the dtor is empty' (It does) and the union was just confusing things.  oops

Comment: *"does Bitmap::~Bitmap() know to destroy it's vector"*: Yes. Joy of Rule of 0 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution of a destructor is defined to execute the body of the destructor function, and then also execute calls to destructors of members and bases .  The pseudo-destructor call executes the destructor.

So yes, the pseudo-destructor call will correctly destroy `pixels` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will implicitly call the destructors of all members and if your class was derived from another class it will call destructor of the base class too.